# Creating UCM Component baseline - only for modified components

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

we have a single application stream with multiple components (UCM Composite baseline) in ClearCase.
It has been split like

```
Alpha Primary Component
|
|___W (Sub component - A application) 
| 
|___X (Sub component - B application)
| 
|___Y (Sub component - C application) 
|
|___Z (Sub component - D application)
```

We use to Make baseline for whole project/stream (Primary `Component- XXX_application_.002`) through GUI it internally reflects in the corresponding components too (`XXX_applcation_.002.yyyy`) where we have code changes but not on the other components.

Is there any way, if I add a baseline for `Alpha` (increment primary baseline) it need to increment the particular component also which have changes (For EX: I have code changes in `B` application (`X` component)?) in `cleartool` command?

I have tried the below command to Make Baseline which is working for single component application, but not for multiple component (composite baseline) application.

```
cleartool mkbl -nc -view $ucmintgview -all -incremental $incrematalBaseline
```

Now I am looking for a command which makes baseline for Primary component which internally need to reflect in the modified application components also not the other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way, if I add a baseline for `Alpha` (increment primary baseline) it needs to increment the particular component also which have changes (For Ex: I have code changes in `B` application (X component)?) in `cleartool` command.

If `Alpha` is a rootless component, with its dependency list composed of the four components `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, then making a baseline on Alpha will be default generate a baseline only on the modified components of its dependency list.

See "[About rooted and rootless ClearCase UCM components](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316953)"

The baseline created on `Alpha` will be a composite baseline: see "[To create a composite baseline](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/t_cre_cmpst_bl.htm)".

So your [mkbl command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm) could target only one component -- `Alpha` --, which would in turn trigger baselines on the modified components of its dependency list.

> A composite baseline is a baseline that selects baselines in other components. You can use a composite baseline to represent the entire project baseline; this is easier than keeping track of a set of baselines, one for each component.

```
cleartool mkbl -comp Alpha@/vobs/aPVob -view $ucmintgview aBaselineName
```

(by default, a baseline is incremental)

Comment: i tried the above command but i am seeing the result like below
Alpha - baseline created like XXX_application_.003.2344 with some random number in the last. I tried to change baseline from XXX_application_.002 to XXX_application_.003. My requirement is Primary (Alpha) need to be incremented to XXX_application_.003 and application component B need to be XXX_application_.003.5843.

Comment: But are you using a rootless component?

Comment: I am not sure how to find it is rootless or rooted. Is there any way i can find that ?

Comment: @Java_Sol simply select the properties of your Alpha component: if you see a root folder, then it is not rootless. Read http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316953, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21257313 or (GUI) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21243311 or ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/v2003/cc_family/ccase/doc/all/cc_tutorial/tut_ucm_vob3.htm

Comment: @Java_Sol ANother tutorial: ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/v2003/cc_family/ccase/doc/all/cc_proj/setting.htm

Comment: yes i am seeing root folder of all the four component baseline under the Alpha component. So i believe it is not rootless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158905/discussion-between-java-sol-and-vonc).

Comment: My issue is fixed with that command. There was a duplicate for the Alpha because of that only i was getting wrong format XXX_application_.003.2344. Now i kept a unique name for this baseline and it is working fine. Thanks